# Kafka Listener stops polling after exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a method annotated with @KafkaLister and I noticed that the kafka consumer stops polling after an exception occurs. How to avoid this behaviour and continue polling?

Here's my Kafka Config:

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory, KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)));
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure retries with back off .

Instead of using `FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)`, which effectively disables retries, you might want to configure a backoff strategy that allows for retries. For example:

```
factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000L, FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS)));
```

Comment: That's a good point, but the consumer would be stuck in retrying again and again on the same message. I need the message to be skipped and the queue to continue working on the next message.

Comment: If that's the case you can use a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` along with `DefaultErrorHandler` to forward failed messages to a dead-letter topic and then continue processing the next messages in the queue.